# Can IPCop connect external server with internal server?

Tags: firewall, svn, openvpn, redmine, ipcop

The sysadmin in my company just resigned (me, intern has to fill that role) & I'm tasked to connect the external bugtracker (Redmine) with the company's Subversion server that is located inside the internal network.

The network looks like this:

[Dedicated server] 202.x.x.x --------- 202.x.x.x [IPCop] 192.168.0.254 ------- 192.168.0.170[SVN server]

And this is how the Redmine subversion connector settings looks like: [image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1690470/redmine%20svn.JPG)

What should I do to connect them? Just tell me what can be done so I could google for the tutorials & documentations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to map a port between the external IP of IPCop to the Internal SVN server. The Redmine configuration would then identify the external IPCop address.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Is the connection will be encrypted? I just discovered VPN technology by googling here & there, spent several hours ago reading OpenVPN explanation on encrypted connection between host-to-host. I think I'll try your suggestion first before starting to look into using vpn since I'm on a deadline.

Comment: If you sent it up for https between the systems.